# C to MIPS How will i convert an if else statement

Tags: if-statement, assembly, mips

I am trying to convert my C code to a MIPS instruction set and i am stuck on how to go about an if and else statement. 
Suppose my code is like this how will do it ?

```
if (x==10)
then
x+=5;
else
x+=20;
```

Any study material or a link will be highly appreciated

Comment: well start with the mips manual and look at the instruction set, should be fairly obvious.

Comment: Converting C source to the target instruction set is what a compiler does.  That is not C code  in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a branch-If-equal `beq` , something like this :

```
beq $t0 $t1 if
#here your else block
j done
if : 
#here your if block 

done:
```

Here is a [link](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) to a MIPS instruction reference.